# Find the position of an element in a javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a javascript object.  My `console.log` outputs this:

```
Object {1: "name", 2: "cost", 3: "country", 4: "date"}
```

How do I find the number that corresponds to "cost"?  I'd like a function that outputs `2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-loopy way of doing it would be:

```js
var yourObject = {1: "name", 2: "cost", 3: "country", 4: "date"};

var result = Object.keys(yourObject).find(key => yourObject[key] === 'cost');

console.log(result) // 2
```

<sub>Assumes you can use ES6 (arrow functions, `find`)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Just iterate over the properties checking their respective values.

```
for (var property in object) {
  if (object[property] === 'cost') {
     /// congratulations, you've found it
  }
}
```

There are of course numerous fancy ways you can do this, e.g. `Object.keys` - but they are all fundamentally the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for not doing the `Object.prototype` extension. Simple, effective solution.

Comment: oh this is really nice!  Thank you!  I'll run both and see the benefits of each.

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd toss an answer in here since Object.Keys() isn't supported before IE9 from what I read.

```
$.each(yourObject, function(key,value){
    if(value === 'cost'){
        console.log(key) // key is 2
    }
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6vLjxa9b/).

Answer (score 0):

Using loadash

_.invert(input).cost